# What does a mercurial revision with no parent mean?

Tags: mercurial

I have a Mercurial repository that is in a strange state now. This is what it looks like in TortoiseHG:

[image: Hg graph]

I didn't think this would be possible. Revision 54 has a parent of "-1 (000000000000)" (i.e. nothing). There's clearly something I don't understand yet about Mercurial, can anyone let me know what this means - and what must have happened for it to get into this state. As far as I know, it's only had stuff pushed and pulled from it - and nobody has been using any wacky extensions.

Revisions 54 and 55 were just adding tags, but if I 'update -C' to revision 54 I end up with ONLY the .hgtags file.

I've made a clone from revision 53 to fix this. But I'd rather understand what happened here, so I can avoid it happening again.

Answer (score 7):

When you look at the [definition of a changeset](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909233855/https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChangeSet), you see:

> Each changeset has zero, one or two parent changesets:
>
> - It has two parent changesets, if the commit was a merge.
> - It has no parent, if the changeset is a root in the repository.
>     **There may be multiple roots in a repository (normally, there is only one), *each representing the start of a branch*.**
>
> "Updating" back to a changeset which already has a child, changing files and then committing creates a new child changeset, thus starting a new branch. Branches can be named.

So maybe this is what you did:

- updating back to 53 (which had already a child '54' of its own back then)
- changing files
- <del>committing, thus starting a new branch from 54, with no parent</del>
  (that would make a second commit with the same parent)

or:

- <del>comitting 53 with a [`--close-branch` option](https://web.archive.org/web/20150912111705/https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PruningDeadBranches),</del>
- potentially a new commit (without switching back to another branch) might begin a new one

**[Ry4an](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8992/ry4an-brase)** (an actual Mercurial specialist ;) ) chimes in and comments:

> `--close-branch` doesn't do anything except hide a branch from a list, and it's undone next time you commit on that branch. It won't create multiple roots.
>
> VonC is right in his diagnosis, **multiple heads**.
>   But no combination of '`update`' and '`commit`' will get you into that state.
>   To end up with multiple roots one usually has done a '`hg pull`' from repo and used `--force` to override an "`unrelated repositories`" warning.

---

("no parent", meaning the parent ids are set to 00000, see ["behind the scene"](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html):

[image]
<sub>(source: [red-bean.com](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/figs/revlog.png))</sub>
)

Comment: If I update back to 53, which already has a 54a child, and then makes changes and commit - wouldn't that just create a 54b child as well? Giving them both a parent of 53?

Comment: @Wilka: true. I must be missing another event, like a `hg commit --close-branch`

Comment: thanks. I can see how that would cause it. However, in this case the branch with chageset 53 is still open. If I close it using --close-branch, the graph displayed in TortoiseHg changes to show the two separate graphs as connect again. So it seems like that wasn't the cause here. Hmmm...

Comment: --close-branch doesn't do anything except hide a branch from a list, and it's undone next time you commit on that branch.  It won't create multiple roots.

Comment: VonC, is right in his diagnosis, multiple heads, but no combination of 'update' and 'commit' will get you into that state.

To end up with multiple roots one usually has done a 'hg pull' from repo and used --force to override an "unrelated repositories" warning.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to see this is if you did `hg update null` after committing rev. 53.  For example, consider this sequence:

```
hg init foo
# create some files
hg addremove
hg commit -m "Revision 0"
# edit, edit, edit
hg commit -m "Revision 1"
hg update null
hg tag -m "Create tag v1.0.0.0" "v1.0.0.0"
```

At this point, `hg log` will show revision 2's parent as -1:0000000000.  Since `hg update null` clears out the working directory, the only file in it would be `.hgtags` (just like you were seeing).

Did you have other tags prior to rev. 53? If my suspicion is correct, they would not be present in your rev. 54 `.hgtags`.

Comment: Note that `hg up 0` does the same thing, and maybe a script or human might have used zero more likely than "null", and without necessarily realizing what it does