# Mercurial creates changesets without parents

Tags: mercurial

I encountered a rather weird result with Mercurial. I've a repository which automatically merges in changes from a CVS repository into a named branch "someBranch". It is all scripted, the only commands that are used on the mercurial side are

```
hg ci -A -u someUser -m someMessage
hg push
```

This worked fine for quite some time. Today, I've noticed that the hg push commands stopped working recently, telling me that it was creating new remote heads on someBranch.

I tried to figure out what is going on. Syncing stopped working with changset 168091. With

```
hg log -G
```

one obtains:

```
o  changeset:   168092:88b141ad6ac5
|  branch:      someBranch
|  user:        someUser
|  date:        Mon Mar 02 16:59:06 2015 +0100
|  summary:     someMessage.
|
o  changeset:   168091:972642c90d59
   branch:      someBranch
   parent:      -1:000000000000
   user:        someUser
   date:        Mon Mar 02 16:58:59 2015 +0100
   summary:     someMessage.

o  changeset:   168090:551d2e1bdbfd
|  branch:      someBranch
|  user:        someUser
|  date:        Mon Mar 02 16:58:52 2015 +0100
|  summary:     someMessage.
|
```

This apparently means that 168091 is not understood to be a child of 168090 which explains why the pushing does not work.

Does anybody have an idea how it can happen that committing yields a new root? The behavior looks odd to me and I am wondering if it is a bug of Mercurial? I'm using version 3.2.4. I'm not running on Windows.

Comment: See [What does a mercurial revision with no parent mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864447/what-does-a-mercurial-revision-with-no-parent-mean) what gives the answer to your question.

Comment: I am aware of this post and it does not answer my question, otherwise I would not have asked it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the repository over a windows share? There has been a bug with hardlinks in some version which causes similar effects. This is solved in version 3.3.2.

See [WhatsNew in Mercurial 3.3.2](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_3.3.2_.282015-03-02.29):

> **Mercurial 3.3.2 (2015-03-02)**
>
> An unscheduled bugfix release to fix...
>
> transaction: really disable hardlink backups ([issue4546](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4546))

Comment: Hi rfkortekaas, thank you for helping. I'm not using any windows, though. Hence I'm assuming that the root cause is something else. I would love to experiment with the newer version, but unfortunately that is difficult in our infrastructure and it will also be difficult to test if this resolves the issue as the problem does not reproduce consistently. In fact, as I wrote, the setup was running fine for quite some time.